# Dragablz Trapezoid Tab Background (WPF)

Tags: wpf, tabs

I'm using Dragablz and Mahapps and I want to be able to switch between modern Material Design type tabs and the trapezoid ones.  I've created two TabablzControl styles I can switch between and have a CustomHeaderViewModel I can change too to adjust its appearance to fit the changing tab style. My header has a stack panel with a textblock and an icon.  I can change the background colour of the SP but in the trapezoid mode I do not know how to change the trapezoid's background to match the colour theme chosen.

Here's my two styles:

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type dragablz:TabablzControl}" x:Key="TabablzControlStyle">
            <Setter Property="NewItemFactory" Value="{x:Static stUi:UINewItem.Factory}" />
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items}" />
            <Setter Property="ClosingItemCallback" Value="{Binding ClosingTabItemHandler}" />
            <Setter Property="ShowDefaultCloseButton" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="AdjacentHeaderItemOffset" Value="-10" />
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource TrapezoidDragableTabItemStyle}" />
            <Setter Property="HeaderMemberPath" Value="Header" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="InterTabController" Value="{StaticResource InterTabController}" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 8 0 0" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type dragablz:TabablzControl}" x:Key="ModernControlStyle">
            <Setter Property="NewItemFactory" Value="{x:Static stUi:UINewItem.Factory}" />
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items}" />
            <Setter Property="ClosingItemCallback" Value="{Binding ClosingTabItemHandler}" />
            <Setter Property="ShowDefaultCloseButton" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="AdjacentHeaderItemOffset" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="HeaderMemberPath" Value="Header" />
            <Setter Property="InterTabController" Value="{StaticResource InterTabController}" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 8 0 0" />
        </Style>
```

[image: Example:]

You can see the area around the stackpanel is lighter than the SP itself. How do I change the trapezoid colour?

Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can create new style based on `TrapezoidDragableTabItemStyle` and override the `Background` property.

After that you must set this new style in `ItemContainerStyle` property of the `TabablzControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could not find an elegant way to do this so I added code to find the "Trapezoid" type in the Loaded() function of my custom header code:

```
        var trap = TryFindParent<Trapezoid>(this);

        if (null != trap)
        {
            trap.Background = Application.Current.Resources["AccentColorBrush1"] as SolidColorBrush;
        }
```

TryFindParent from here : [How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type)

It will do for me. Changing colour will typically only be done once and the setting saved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I marked Daniel's answer as correct but wanted to just illustrate an example of the code for that in case someone doesn't know how.

```
Style oldStyle = TryFindResource("TrapezoidDragableTabItemStyle") as Style;
Style newHeaderStyle = new(typeof(DragablzItem), oldStyle);
Setter backgroundSetter = new Setter() { Property = BackgroundProperty, Value = Brushes.LightBlue };
newHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(backgroundSetter);
MyTabablzControl.ItemContainerStyle = newHeaderStyle;
```